# Getting link content size

Tags: php, filesize

I have a page with more than 100 links(xml files). With some prework I'm getting the links  and saving all the data to a server, but I don't want to save that files which size are smaller than xxKb. How could I get the size?

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the links"? Do you mean that you are retrieving pages of content from a webserver? If so, how are you doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($links as $link) {
   $data = file_get_contents($link);
   if (strlen($data) >= $min_size) {
      file_put_contents($data, 'some file name on your server');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the [`filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) method:

```
foreach($links as $link){
    if(filesize($link) > xx){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Not particularly reliable on URLS. content-length headers may not be present or may be forged.

Answer (score 1):

Try `filesize` function.  From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php):

```
int filesize ( string $filename )
```

> Gets the size for the given file.
>
> Parameters
>   filename -
>   Path to the file.
>
> Return Values
>
> Returns the size of the file in bytes, or FALSE (and generates an error of level E_WARNING) in case of an error.